# Jenkins helm Chart not adding JENKINS_OPTS environment variable

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I am installing Jenkins from the helm chat `jenkins-0.8.2`,  trying to add the JENKINS_OPTS environment variable. But its not getting added to my deployment.

Here is my values file.

```
Master:
  Name: jenkins-master
  Image: "jenkins/jenkins"
  ImageTag: "lts"
  ImagePullPolicy: "Always"
  Component: "jenkins-master"
  UseSecurity: true  
  JavaOpts: "-Xms512m -Xmx2048m"
  JenkinsUriPrefix: /jenkins
  JenkinsOpts: '--prefix=/jenkins'
```

Also see this in the `jenkins-master-deployment.yaml` file.

```
env:
            - name: JAVA_OPTS
              value: "{{ default "" .Values.Master.JavaOpts}}"
            - name: JENKINS_OPTS
              value: "{{ if .Values.Master.JenkinsUriPrefix }}--prefix={{ .Values.Master.JenkinsUriPrefix }} {{ end }}{{ default "" .Values.Master.JenkinsOpts}}"
```

Its missing JEKNIS_OPT env.

```
# kg deploy jenkins-jenkins -o yaml |grep OPTS
        - name: JAVA_OPTS
```

How can I get this value added in helm chat?

Thanks
SR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Current stable chart didn't have the `JENKINS_OPT` option. I have to check out the code from github and install the helm chart. my version chart `jenkins-0.13.1`

```
helm install jenkins  --name jenkins --namespace  jenkins -f jenkins-values.yaml --debug
```

Test it:

```
# kg deploy -o yaml |grep OPTS
          - name: JAVA_OPTS
          - name: JENKINS_OPTS
```